# Problem while parsing excel file with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am parsing xlsx file with pandas. This file contains sheet named '1A'. Nonetheless when I use `pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='1A')` I get `XLRDError: No sheet named <'1A'>`. I've tried `pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)` and noticed that in returned dictionary **A** font in dict's key differs from **A** in all other places. [image]

What can be wrong here and how can I fix that problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you already have the dict of dataframes, why not just use `df_dict.keys()` to get the correct key name?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney there are a lot of such keys (approximately 36) and it'll be hard to choose the needed one